# New permission is not found after successfully calling Invite in Graph Api

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am using Microsoft Graph to manipulate permissions of files that are stored in a SharePoint document library.  When I use Invite to grant permission to an email address outside of the SharePoint site organization, I get a successful response that includes a permission ID.

Looking at the permissions from SharePoint, I can see that it successfully created a share link for the provided email address that grants the requested permission.  However, the permission does not appear in the list of permissions for that item when I query them using Microsoft Graph, and when I query the created permission using its ID, I get a `NotFound` response.

My goal is to access the sharing link `webUrl` of the permission, but the response returned when I first create it has a null 'link' facet and there does not appear to be any way to retrieve the permission after it has been created or to access sharing links for the file.

Is this a bug or is there a way to access the sharing link for a permission granted to a file stored in a SharePoint document library?

Here are my steps:

1. `POST /sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/Invite` with request body:

   ```
   {
     "requireSignIn": true,
     "sendInvitation": false,
     "roles": ["write"],
     "recipients": [{ "email": "{email}" }],
     "message": ""
   }
   ```
2. Reponse (`Success - Status Code 200`):

   ```
   {
     "@odata.context":
       "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(permission)",
     "value": [
       {
         "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.permission",
         "grantedTo": {
           "user": {
             "displayName": "{email}"
           }
         },
         "id": "{permissionId}",
         "roles": ["write"]
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
3. I can verify from SharePoint that the permission was created for the email address and is associated with a specific sharing link
4. `GET /sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/permissions/{permissionId}`
5. Response (`Failure - Status Code 404`):

   ```
   {
       "error": {
           "code": "itemNotFound",
           "message": "The resource could not be found.",
           "innerError": {
               "request-id": "f256c838-64fd-4679-b64f-7c62bf6ef178",
               "date": "2018-03-19T16:22:09"
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. Permission is also not listed when querying the list of permissions for that item

Answer (score 1):

After some fiddling around myself, I found the solution.
The permissions isn't actually granted until the recipient clicks the link and "accepts"  the invitation.

Try having your recipient click the link in the invitation and then check if you can find it.

Kind regards,
R Schouten